# Need help in modifying OWIN (Katana) for running VS2013's MVC WebApplication in Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mono, raspberry-pi, owin

I want to run Visual Studio 2013's default MVC WebApplication in Raspberry Pi 2.  I managed to install mono 4.0.1 and Lighttpd as the web server, and I was able to get this default MVC WebApplication (with no authentication) run on the Raspberry machine.  However, when I tried the same MVC WebApplication but with "Individual Authentication", it gives the following error:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method 'HttpApplication.RegisterModule' not found.
```

After googling, I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212512/missing-method-errors-when-running-asp-net-app-with-xsp-on-linux/28289791?noredirect=1#comment48377110_28289791) that this method 'RegisterModule()' is not implemented in mono's System.Web.HttpApplication.  And the solution is to rebuild OWIN.  I have never done that before.  I used 'Git Bash' to clone the Katana as follow:

```
git clone https://git01.codeplex.com/katanaproject
```

then modified the PreApplicationStart.cs accordingly, and then run 'build' in command prompt, and it successfully created the Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll under the project directory.  I then tried to replace the original dll with this new one in Visual Studio 2013, and hit F5 to try to run it, and get the following errors:

```
The type 'Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

and

```
'Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext' does not contain a definition for 'GetUserManager' and the best extension method overload 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.OwinContextExtensions.GetUserManager<TManager>(Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext)' has some invalid arguments
```

Is this the proper way to rebuild the OWIN and update this Microslft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll?  Any suggestion to get it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got it work by using Visual Studio 2013 to build the project Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb directly, then use the result Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll to replace the one used in the original MVC WebApplication project.