# Mono - gets System.Web.AsyncInvoker.Invoke Error in MVC WebApplication with OWIN SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono, raspberry-pi, signalr

I am trying to migrate an existing MVC WebApplication to run in a Linux machine using Mono (4.0.1).  This existing WebApplication is based on the MVC template in Visual Studio 2013 plus it uses SignalR & OWIN.  After weeks of googling and struggling, and following the sites [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212512/missing-method-errors-when-running-asp-net-app-with-xsp-on-linux/28289791?noredirect=1#comment48377110_28289791) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219588/problems-with-running-mvc-webapplication-owin-in-vs2013-in-raspberry-pi-using) and [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=29665), I can finally get to this far:

[image]

```
Error: System.Web.AsyncInvoker.Invoke (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) ...
```

I read in the Mono Compatibility Page [here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/) that Mono has only **limited ASP.NET 4.5 async stack support**.  Is this the cause of the above error?  Should I give up on running SignalR 2.x in Mono?  Is using SignalR 1.x a possible workaround?

Thanks in advance for your help.