# Missing Method MachineKey::Protect() error when running SignalR 1.2.1 with Mono 3.12.1 & Raspberry Pi

Tags: model-view-controller, web-applications, mono, raspberry-pi, signalr

I am 'migrating' a MVC WebApplication to a Raspberry Pi 2.  The original Web Application uses SignalR 2.x.  After googling for weeks, I believe that the lastest Mono 4.0.1 only supports self-hosted SignalR server due to OWIN issue (ref [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212512/missing-method-errors-when-running-asp-net-app-with-xsp-on-linux/28289791?noredirect=1#comment48377110_28289791)). So I tried to revert back to SignalR 1.x to avoid using OWIN middleware approach.

I followed the SignalR 1.x tutorial [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/older-versions/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) and was able to run the sample, except that when `$.connection.hub.start()` is called in the client's browser, the xsp4 server throws the following exception:

```
Missing method System.Web.Security.MachineKey::Protect(byte[],string[]) in assembly /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Web/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll, referenced in assembly /tmp/pi-temp-aspnet-0/1543474b/assembly/shadow/c3a92c68/a3f2fa86_605bd6ee_00000001/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb.dll
```

The `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs()` in `Application_Start()` seems to work OK as I can get the generated `/signalr/hubs` script without problem.

It seems that this function `System.Web.Security.MachineKey::Protect()` is not implemented in mono.  I wonder if anyone has any workaround to this error.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If I remember correctly, this was a bug in an earlier version of SignalR 1.x, can you try updating to the latest 1.x and see if it's fixed?